# How do I check for text inside a <div>?

Tags: ruby, watir, firewatir

I am trying to access some text that is located in a DIV.
I need to check to see if the page holds the text so I can return a true or false.
The code I am using is below:

```
cancel = browser.text.include?("Current Cancelled")
if cancel == true
puts "Line item cancelled"
else
puts "****Line item not cancelled****"
end
```

But it returns false every time.
Here is a code snippet of what I am looking into:

[image]

Comment: I don't know ruby but my first (and only) guess is that it's not recognized because it has different styles ("current" is in a span while "cancelled" isn't)

Comment: Wow. That makes sense. I wonder how I could split these up and get them to combine for my check.

Comment: In the future, it'd help get answers if you'd use the actual source, rather than a screen capture. There's no way I'd bother typing in a full XML sample, while having it available to copy and paste when working on a solution makes it easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probable reason this isn't working is because the string you're testing for contains a newline character and a non breaking space.

This could work...

```
if browser.div(:text, /Current.*Cancelled/).exists?
  puts "Line item cancelled"
else
  puts "****Line item not cancelled****"
end
```

or

```
if browser.text =~ /Current.*Cancelled/
  puts "Line item cancelled"
else
  puts "****Line item not cancelled****"
end
```

etc.

Comment: This was my thinking as well, KF just beat me to it by a few hours

You could even try this to be sure

Comment: puts browser.table(:Class, 'basic-table').cell(:text, /Current/).text

That should print out the text for just that one cell so you have a better idea what is 'in there' according to the DOM.

Comment: I used the first line. Worked great! Thanks a bunch kinofrost.

Comment: @Curtis Miller No problem. I live to give. And to beat Chuck to the answers. Just kidding :).

Answer (score 5):

I'd really recommend using Nokogiri to parse the content.

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<div><span class="label">Current</span>Cancelled</div>')
doc.at('//div/span[@class="label"]/../text()').text # => "Cancelled"

(doc.at('//div/span[@class="label"]/../text()').text.downcase == 'cancelled') # => true
!!(doc.at('//div/span[@class="label"]/../text()').text.downcase['cancelled']) # => true
```

Something like one of the two bottom statements will get you a usable true/false.

Comment: I attempted at this 'Nokogiri' stuff but it isn't really giving me what I wanted. Thanks for showing me what Nokogiri is, I might be able to use it for something in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Watir's Browser object has now the **#elements_by_xpath** method... 
See Watir's [API](http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.5/)

Just pin-point your DIV and ask for its **#text** method. Pretty much like what [the Tin Man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128421/the-tin-man) suggests but without requiring nokogiri.

AFIK Watir uses internally exactly for the purpose of locating elements (it's a dependency gem that Watir installs) anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the fact that the text is inside a table is causing this problem.

You might consider drilling into the table doing:

```
cancel = browser.table(:class, 'basic-table').each { |row|
  test = row.text.include?("Current Cancelled")
  return test if test == true
}
```

Comment: Is there anything stopping one from using browser.table(:class, 'basic-table').text.include?("Current Cancelled") instead? Would be quicker. Also, to check this, one could try accessing the DIV from irb.

Comment: @kinofrost Probably not, I just wanted to have something I thought would work for sure.  Your suggestion is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

> Wow. That makes sense. I wonder how I
>   could split these up and get them to
>   combine for my check.

Okay, here's a really quick draft:

```
div = browser.table(:class, 'basic-table').div(:text, /Cancelled/)

cancel = div.exist? and div.span(:index, 1).text == 'Current'
if cancel
   puts "Line item cancelled"
else
   puts "****Line item not cancelled****"
end
```

Comment: This ought to work also, but frankly I think the use of the regular expression to look for a single match (the other post you made at about the same time) reads a lot cleaner and is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You could also combine a few of the regular expression approaches below (mostly those from Kinofrost), with the idea of narrowing it down to looking just inside a single cell within the table.  That should be faster, and less prone to a false alert should the words 'Current' and 'Cancelled' occur in that order with anything between them, elsewhere on the page.

```
if browser.table(:class, 'basic-table').cell(:text, /Current.*Cancelled/).exists?
   puts "Line item cancelled"
else
   puts "****Line item not cancelled****"
end
```